# Why is my code calculating the percentage incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript. I wrote this function to calculate the percentage of three values, but the output is showing incorrectly. It is showing `176.33` instead of `74.3`

```js
function percentageCalculator(history, math, science) {
  let percentage = history + math + science * 100 / 300;
  console.log(percentage);
};

percentageCalculator(88, 65, 70);
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I expect the function to give me percentage of the given arguments which is 74.3.

Comment: You forgot your parentheses `(history + math + science)`. Voted to close because it's a small typographical error.

Comment: Your code is currently being evaluated like so `(history + math + ((science * 100) / 300))`, use `(` `)` to group your operations

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thanks guys. (This place is legendary)

Comment: More info about what operators are evaluated first can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
let percentage = (history + math + science) * 100 / 300;
```

Like math, JavaScript also have calculation order.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the appropriate surrounding brackets. You could just divide by 3 directly instead of multiplying by 100 and then dividing by 300:

```js
function percentageCalculator(history, math, science) {
  const percentage = (history + math + science) / 3;
  return percentage;
}

console.log(percentageCalculator(88, 65, 70).toFixed(1));
```